# Enter recovery mode from command line

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, command-line

Does anyone know if there's a way to get an Android phone to reboot into recovery mode, from the Android command line?

Note:

I do *NOT* have adb access.

I do *NOT* know the magic power-on sequence to do it from the boot loader. I've tried the common things and nothing works.

I *DO* have root. (And can enter commands directly on the device using a terminal emulator.)

I know it's possible, somehow, because applications like ROM Manager do it. But how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, `reboot` binary provides a `recovery` switch. After switching to root, execute this command:

`/system/bin/reboot recovery`

This may not work if your manufacturer doesn't support it. ROM Manager type apps uses API of Android which you can't access via Terminal Emulator directly.

Comment: You shouldn't need the full path for `reboot`, but this is exactly right.

Comment: @MatthewRead Yup, full path is really not needed. :) But, I didn't want to leave a chance in case someone messed up with `PATH` variable.

Comment: @Otech1408 You have to have a rooted device to do this.

Comment: on non rooted devices you can achieve this through adb: `adb reboot recovery`

Comment: You might need to type `su` in terminal to gain root access before running `reboot recovery`.

Comment: Hi. What would those Android APIs be? Do you know? (PS: I have access to the internal APIs, so I can use them in case they're needed.)

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following command on stock Android 5.0 and 6.0.1, CM [14](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/enter-recovery-mode-from-command-line/139138#comment206659_139138), and Android 8.1.0 with graceful shutdown and reboot to recovery:

```
su -c 'svc power reboot recovery'
```

It worked on Android 4.4.2 as well but the shutdown appeared to be low-level. It requires root access though.

Alternatively, if you're running Android [KitKat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1/services/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java#2235) or above<sup><sup>*</sup></sup> and have root access, you can try this command in a terminal app:

```
su -c 'setprop sys.powerctl reboot,recovery'
```

- replace *su -c* with *adb shell* to run the command using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)
- replace *reboot,recovery* with *reboot* to reboot the device
- replace *reboot,recovery* with *shutdown* to [shutdown](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1/services/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java#2221) the device

**Note** that all of those `setprop` commands would do a low-level (unclean; not graceful) shutdown/reboot.

In Android [Lollipop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java#2297) and above<sup><sup>*</sup></sup>, you can also try:

```
su -c 'setprop ctl.start pre-recovery'
```

---

For Android Jelly Bean and below, SS-3's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21052/96277) appears to be the only possible solution.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup></sup> <sub>The last version on which the command is tested upon is stock Android 6.0.1.</sub>

Comment: CM's su binary I suppose doesn't have  `-c` argument, so first switch to root user using `su` and then execute the quoted command

Comment: I believe it was running either cupcake or donut. Regardless, it went off to the great phone recyling centre in the sky long ago. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @DavidGiven : It may be appearing quite silly that I revived an old question but I did that because you didn't mention a particular Android version so I tried to use it as an opportunity to mention what would work not only for you but for other and successive Android versions as well. It also helped me in avoiding  forking a duplicate question but for other Android versions.

Comment: The "su -c 'svc power reboot recovery'" is working on my cm14.1 (android 7.1) based rom. It is shutting down gracefully before rebooting into recovery. This is the best solution i have come across so far.