# Failed to load Recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, fastboot

One of my friend had a Huawei Y210, it locked because of so many wrong pattern attempt. Unfortunately he hasn't google account to login with it.

I want to hard reset it but it fails to load Recovery mode by pressing Volume Up + Power for more than 10 seconds or less!, I tested any key combination but only it normally boots and shows locked screen.

I tried `fastboot -i 0x12d1 flash recovery recovery.img` and without vendor id, it only waits for device.

Also I added `51-android.rules` to `udev` and restart `udev` but nothing happend and only wait for device.

and `adb` only waits for device.

I have no idea what I should do. If I setup a bootable sdcard, Can it boots from it? 
or like NoteII that can goes to recovery mode by soldering some resistors to a male usb connector and plug it, there is something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter recovery mode from command line](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/enter-recovery-mode-from-command-line)

Comment: No duplicate, if you read them correctly you can distinguish them

Comment: Duplicate or not, it is related. The only difference is that your device is locked because of wrong password attempts. You are looking to get into Recovery without hardware buttons, as you state they didn't work. That question covers that. You also state that `adb` wasn't working as it was 'waiting for device'.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the way:

Turned it off and then connect it to computer, `adb` found it as recovery then i ran `adb reboot recovery` and then it reboots to recovery.

I found that volume up and down keys are semi broken and for this reason it could not to load recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

To enter fastboot mode hold 
vol+ vol- AND power for about 5 seconds; then check with `fastboot devices`

this assumes you've already installed the adb drivers from hi suite or some universal set.

once you're here you can flash a custom recovery or extract the factory recovery from the firmware zip.

http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/downloads/detail/index.htm?id=14221