# How to boot into emergency mode in LG ( L3 E400)

Tags: rom-flashing, lg, volume-buttons

How can I enter into emergency mode, using adb or command or any application, without pressing down <kbd>volume</kbd> button. Because, my device's <kbd>volume down</kbd> button is broken.

Comment: Related: [Enter recovery mode from command line](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/enter-recovery-mode-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

After installing appropriate usb drivers, and enabling usb debugging in developer options in your device. Enter this code to reboot in recovery/emergency mode (don't know if that term is specific to your device):

`adb reboot recovery` you should boot into recovery mode.

If successful you should see  a number of options:

- reboot system
- apply update from SD card
- apply update from cache
- wipe data/factory reset

try navigating the options with the other vol button and power button as "enter"